# Is there a way to run Autocad commands on the viewer using Forge Viewer API?

Tags: autocad, cad, autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-viewer

I wanted to confirm if there is a way to run autocad commands (specifically the AREA command) on my dwg opened using the Forge Viewer Javascript API.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The Forge Viewer is a WEBGL/javascript web component. It is not running an AutoCAD engine behind the scene. The Forge Viewer consumes/displays information extracted from a DWG file using the Forge Model Derivative API. However, if an AutoCAD region was present in the DWG, the Model Derivative API will extract a property that is accessible there.
Now if you are interested to run an AutoCAD command, you got 2 options depending on what you need. You can either use the [Forge Design Automation](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v2/overview/) (running the AutoCAD engine), or use the [AutoCAD 360](https://client.autocad360.com/) which can run on mobile or a web page.

Comment: The link for design automation is pointing to Model Derivative API. If you meant Model Derivative then I had tried it to no avail (2D drawings don't give properties.). Can you please explain how I can make use of Design Automation to find area? It asks me to post an activity, which runs in the autocad engine. I am not sure how I can proceed with that information.
Thanks

Comment: yes, sorry, here it is https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v2/overview/ - an activity can be running an plugin command or simple script - see an example [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/design.automation-custom-data-viewer). This sample extracts Xdata, but if you run some code to get the AREA information, you can do something similar.

Comment: Can you please help me understand how I can execute the command (AREA) using the APIs?

Comment: @cyrille thank you - would you be able to elaborate on the difference between using A360 and the forge design automation api to do the same thing - pros vs cons?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not run AutoCAD commands on Forge Viewer even the source file format is dwg, the reason is that the source file will be translated to SVF/F2D to make it be viewed by web browser, it's totally nothing related to AutoCAD anymore.

Comment: can't we access certain properties from the forge viewer though, which may include area?